# Can I exclude a commerce address by ID when retrieving a list of addresses?

Tags: plugin-craftcommerce, array, loop

I would like to retrieve a list of all commerce customer addresses except for one. When working with entries, this can be done with the `{id: 'not ' ~ some.id }` parameter. This doesn't seem to work with `craft.commerce.customer.addresses`.

I'm currently achieving what I need with the following code:

```
{% set customerAddresses = craft.commerce.customer.addresses %}
{% for address in customerAddresses %}
    {% if address.id != craft.lhngroups.orgCommerceAddressId %}
        output the address
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

This works, but it throws off some `{{ loop.index }}` operations I'm trying to perform since the actual array of addresses contains 1 more address than what I'm displaying.

Answer (score 3):

I still haven't found a succinct way to exclude a particular address by ID within the commerce customer addresses tags, but I did come up with the following as a way to get a nice clean set of addresses I want to iterate over.

Rather than use a conditional in my loop, I decided to create the collection first, with the address I want to exclude being kept out of the collection. This gets the job done!

```
{% set customerAddresses = [] %}

{% for address in craft.commerce.customer.addresses %}
    {% if address.id != craft.lhngroups.orgCommerceAddressId %}
        {% set customerAddresses = customerAddresses|merge([address]) %}
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 1):

The following is a very straightforward variable to put within your own plugin's variables/variables.php file:

```
function getCommerceAddressById($id)
{
    return craft()->commerce_addresses->getAddressById($id);
}
```

In your case you use it to return just the addresses you need.